# How to generate dynamically unique id for form which is popup form to comment every post but it get last post id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to comment on a post with a popup form including 4-5 fields. I the popup form I want to provide the post id of the post to comment on, but when posting this id through a hidden field, it always results in the last post id. How can I generate a dynamically different id which gives me the exact post id?

```
<form id="forms">
  <label for="email">Facility :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="facility" name="facility" maxlength="50">  
  //printing{{$customerpost->id}} this value gives correct post id
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="{{$customerpost->id}}" id="hidden">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  id ="submit">Post It! </button>
</form>

$( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
    var data;
    data = new FormData();

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN':  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            authorization:  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    });

    data.append('facility', $("#facility").val());
    data.append('hidden', $("#hidden").val());

    console.log(data);
    alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/bidon/',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert("sucess");
            alert( data );
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I log to the console, it always gives me the last post id. How can I solve this using the Laravel framework?

Comment: Hello @Jiwan Pokhrel,
Can you share laravel code on above question?

Comment: I believe you are appending several "hidden" fields to your modal as you are never deleting the last one you added, so when trying to get the value is just obtaining the first field with that it can find.

Answer (score 0):

Simple do this on click

```
<!-- Add post id in attribute -->
<div data-id="12345" class="btn"> add comment </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('click','.btn',function(){
    // get id from         
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // set id to hidden attribute
    // $('#hidden').attr('data-id', id);
    // or set id to hidden input
    $('#hidden').val(id);
    // Show form
    $('#forms').slideUp();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Being a static id gives a post last id